# Default internal class is visible for other projects - why?

Tags: c#

I have the following Book class (it's to long to paste it all):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GradeBook
{
    internal class Book
    {
```

and the BookTests class, that creates a variable of this Book type:

```
using System;
using Xunit;

namespace GradeBook.Tests
{
    public class BookTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            var book = new Book("");

        }
    }
}
```

both in separate projects. 
It doesn't show error, despite of internal modifier, but i don't know why. The Book class also doesn't find a reference from second file.

Comment: Is there an `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo(...)]` line anywhere in your first project? Traditionally in `AssemblyInfo.cs`

Comment: Does this file exist when working with VS Code, not only with Visual Studio? I don't know where to look for.

Comment: It might not exist -- it's not generated by default any more. Just do a "Find in files" for "InternalsVisibleTo"

Comment: "No results found"

Comment: Oh well, worth checking

Comment: I solved the problem, so for those who will eventually find this post later:
I added additional reference to one of the .csproj file - what corrupted project, and then, following this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore?tabs=netcore2x I used in command prompt "dotnet restore" command, which fixed both the corrupted project and strange behavior of the class. And I found AssemblyInfo file under Debug  folder.